# OpenDKIM not signing mail sent to relay host with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postfix, email-server, opendkim

I recently migrated a server from Ubuntu 14.04 to one running 18.04 but with the same mail setup. I simply copied over Postfix's main.cf and the contents of /etc/mail/opendkim over.

The server is sending mail to a remote mail host over the LAN without problems. However, opendkim refuses to sign the emails as it was before.

My postfix.cf file:

```
myhostname = host.domain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
relayhost = 10.10.10.105
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mydestination =
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
compatibility_level = 2
```

/etc/opendkim.conf

```
Syslog                  yes
UMask                   007
Socket                  inet:8892@localhost
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
OversignHeaders         From
UserID                  opendkim
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
KeyTable                /etc/mail/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            /etc/mail/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList      /etc/mail/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           /etc/mail/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

The TrustedHosts file contains both the IP and the host name of the sending machine (and hostname -f is correct). Both machines are on the same domain.

I see no errors in either the sender's logs or that of remote mail host. If I shut down the opendkim daemon on the sender, I see postfix complain that it can't connect to the opendkim socket.

I have tried setting the milter_protocol to 2 (it was originally 6) but that has no effect.

Looking at the headers on the mail received from the affected host, there is no mention of dkim.

Comment: What are the `From:` and maybe `Sender:` headers of an outgoing message? What is the SigningTable?

Comment: @kubanczyk The From: header shows the sending user with the hostname of the sending machine (not the relay, but that's correct I think as it's in the TrustedHosts). There doesn't seem to be a Sender: header. The SigningTable shows domain.com default._domainkey.domain.com. I have not changed anything in /etc/mail/opendkim from when it was working with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: BTW the sending host and the relay are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `LogWhy yes` to to opendkim.conf turns on verbose logging. This reveals that there is no signing key for the sending host (host.domain.com).

SigningTable is set to sign mails from specific domains, but not individual **hosts** on those domains. This is correct behaviour.

The sending host is giving a FQDN when it sends out mail through the relay (host@host.domain.com). I therefore need to work out how to get the sending host to send out as host@domain.com, not host@host.domain.com so that the relay will sign its mail on behalf of the domain. I don't need to run opendkim on the sending host.

With the Postfix configuration on Ubuntu 18.04, I had to add `masquerade_domains = domain.com` to main.cf, whereas Ubuntu 14.04 did not need this.